# Gradle Jenkins lint report

Tags: android, xml, jenkins, gradle, lint

Help please. When i run command `gradle lint` in terminal, I see the following output:

```
:facebook:lint                 
Ran lint on variant release: 65 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 65 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:new/facebook/build/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to new\facebook\build\lint-results.xml
:msmandroidapp:lint                 
Ran lint on variant release: 71 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 71 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:new/msmandroidapp/build/l
int-results.html
Wrote XML report to new\msmandroidapp\build\lint-results.xml
:ringprogress:lint                 
Ran lint on variant release: 4 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 4 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file: new/ringprogress/ringprogress/build/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to new\ringprogress\ringprogress\build\lint-results.xml
```

I only care about the `:msmandroidapp:lint` results. It shows `71 issues found`.

However when I run the same from Jenkins, I see **less** issues detected for `:msmandroidapp:lint` (only 67). I looked in the report and saw that in report I have got 67 issues too. A snippet of html report is below:

```
Lint Report
Check performed at Tue Apr 01 14:35:13 FET 2014.
8 errors and 59 warnings found:
```

So where is the difference in detected number of issues coming from? Maybe they are overwritten by another projects?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a lint versioning issue.  The Android lint Jenkins plug-in you are using may not be the same version as the current Android SDk lint tool.  This would mean that the Jenkins lint may let some things "pass", where your local Android SDK lint will flag the same code as an error.